# What material would support the outer ring of a woven children's nest swing?

Tags: metal, play-structures, porch-swing

I would like to build a nest swing for my daughter (similar to attached image) but am not sure what I can use as the base ring under the rope. I have considered bending some plumbers copper pipe into a circle and soldering with a straight coupler, then lagging and rope. But not sure this will be strong enough.

And ideas on where I can find a metal ring of around 1.2m diameter off the shelf?

I suppose another option is a sheet of wood and a jigsaw, but not ideal.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1" or 1-1/4" flexible polyethylene pipe, such as is used for irrigation systems, would probably do well. It would be rigid enough to hold shape, yet light enough to not knock a kid out in a forehead shot. If you're concerned about rigidity, nest one size inside another.

You should be able to buy it by the foot from big-box home stores, or in small coils at most hardware stores. You'd want to use an interior splicer, or a wooden dowel if one isn't readily available.

Comment: Thanks! Have ordered some pipe, will let you know how it goes. I'll post a photo of the finished swing :)